# Plot scatter plots over a shapefile using Python

Tags: python, geopandas

I want to plot a scatter plot over a shapefile plot, but when I plot the scatter, the first layer disappears.

The code I use is the following:

```
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(30,30))
barcelona.plot(ax=ax,column='n_distri',legend=True)
plt.scatter(df.longitud, df.latitud)
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For continuous plotting on the same converse, you need to match the ax.
It creates a new plot without options for ax.

```
plt.scatter(df.longitud, df.latitud)
```

Use this instead of the one above.

```
ax.scatter(df.longitud, df.latitud)
```

If you need to adjust the coordinate system, etc., change the points long and lat to GeoDataFrame and plot, use the ax option.

```
barcelona.plot(ax=ax,column='n_distri',legend=True)
gdf_of_points.plot(ax=ax)
```